# Lodash, Uncaught TypeError: _.remove is not a function

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am including lodash v.4.17.11 js file in my HTML web page using HTML `script` tag.

```
<body>
...
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.min.js"></script> 
</body>
```

Some functions like `_.filter()` or `_.reduce()` are working fine, but `_.remove()` gave me:

> Uncaught TypeError: _.remove is not a function

It seems that this function does not exist in the library file! although it is listed in the documentation.

How should I do to solve this? Thank you!

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#remove

Comment: Can you add the line where you import/require `lodash` from you code?

Comment: ```<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.min.js"></script>

</body>```

Comment: Are you importing specifically functions from lodash or using the entire lib? for example do you have something like `import { filter } from 'lodash'`?

Comment: No, I am including the whole library file from cdnjs url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the `core` lib. It seems you need more than the `core`:

instead of:
`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.min.js`

use:
`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js`

Here are more details on the differences:

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Build-Differences

**For your convenience:**

4 kB (gzipped) core build (63 methods; Backbone ≥ v1.3.0 compatible)

`_.assignIn, _.before, _.bind, _.chain, _.clone, _.compact, _.concat, _.create, _.defaults, _.defer, _.delay, _.each, _.escape, _.every, _.filter, _.find, _.flatten, _.flattenDeep, _.forEach, _.has, _.head, _.identity, _.indexOf, _.isArguments, _.isArray, _.isBoolean, _.isDate, _.isEmpty, _.isEqual, _.isFinite, _.isFunction, _.isNaN, _.isNull, _.isNumber, _.isObject, _.isRegExp, _.isString, _.isUndefined, _.iteratee, _.keys, _.last, _.map, _.matches, _.max, _.min, _.mixin, _.negate, _.noConflict, _.noop, _.once, _.pick, _.reduce, _.result, _.size, _.slice, _.some, _.sortBy, _.tap, _.thru, _.toArray, _.uniqueId, _#value, & _.values`

**Limitations:**

- No _.matchesProperty iteratee shorthand
- No deep property path support
- No lazy evaluation
- No placeholder support
- No robust cloning (arrays & plain objects only)
- No support for maps, sets, & typed arrays

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick, I will update the question to have the url inside as it is an important info.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I used `"lodash": "^4.17.21"`, it worked normally until a pretty day, I don't know why I received this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _.remove is not a function
```

Other `lodash` functions still work, except the `_.remove()`.

I tried to remove and reinstall `lodash` by `npm` but it didn't solve the problem.
I also looked up in folder `node_modules` and found file `remove.js` was still there.

Then I tried `import { remove } from 'lodash'` as an alternative way and finally the error's gone.

Hope this help!